# Flutter game controller for mobile is not show at the front of layer

Tags: flutter, controller, flame

I try to make a mobile game by using flutter flame, but the controller is not show at the front of the layer even I set priority to 10.

I try to make a priority of controller layer, but it's doesn't work. how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code it is hard to know what the exact problem is, but I would guess that you have added the controller to the game directly, instead of to the viewport. This means that the `World` will be rendered in front of it.

To solve this, just add the controller to the viewport like this:

```dart
camera.viewport.add(controller);
```